# Animate <div> when user has scrolled to the bottom of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my page, I have a div element containing copyright information.

I would like to

1. detect if the user has scrolled all the way to the bottom of the page.
2. if so, have the div slide down.

It would also be nice if there was a way that JQuery could tell if I am near the box without having to scroll over it to display the copy right as well.

Thanks, DoubleDogg6

Comment: Where is the "div box"? What is it's position? Fixed or relative? Is it at the bottom of the page, a few pixels up or something?

Comment: Sorry for not giving enough information @minseong, the div is at the bottom of the page, the position is not set, but by default I would assume it is relative. It is at the very bottom, with the document having a 8px margin only at the bottom. This margin is attached via CSS to the HTML tag its self since adding a margin to the BODY would not work for me. Thank you for readying and helping. If there is not a way to do this that would be okay, I just didn't know if there was a way to make it look cleaner.

Comment: But then when the div slides down it won't be graceful, it will slide below the page and force a scroll to read it. Surely you want a slide up?

Comment: No, I decide to just leave it always displayed, I will set it to a pixel amount or would em be better?

Comment: Pixel amount is better, unless you measure everything else with em.

Answer (score 0):

1. It's simple to detect this.
   take a look at this jfiddle:

[Detect scrolling to the bottom](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/gWD66/)

```js
 $(window).scroll(function() {   
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
       alert("bottom!");
   }
});
```

2.
For sliding down a div read the documentation for .slideDown()

[jQuery .slideDown()](http://api.jquery.com/slidedown/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want jQuery, then this should suffice

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  if ($(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height() == $(document).height()){
    // and now, slideDown
    $("#your-div-id").animate({
      height: /* whatever your final height should be */
    }, 200);
  } else if ($(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height() < $(document).height() + 50) {
    $("#your-div-id").animate({
      height: /* whatever your original height was */
    }, 200);
  }
});
```

Of course, you combine the [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function with others to maybe fade in the text or something, and change the speed at which the animation happens, currently 200ms.

You also want your div's overflow-y set to hidden,

```
#your-div-id {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Check out this [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/theonlygusti/meaL2zo3/).